# RxJS : how to transform an Observable<Observable<Thing>> into Observable<Thing[]>

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I'm not an expert with rxJS pipes, i have a problem I think is simple, my code boils down to :

```
getThings = (): Observable<Thing[]> => 
    this.getThingIds().pipe(
        mergeMap((thingIds: number[]) => 
            thingIds.map((id: number) => this.http.get<Thing>(`url${id}`))
        )
    );
```

The problem is that this returns an `Observable<Observable<Thing>>`. Is there a way to transform this into the needed `Observable<Thing[]>` with an operator ? or am I completely wrong from the beginning.

Basically I need to do one request for each ids received from `getThingIds` and just  transform all thoses results into an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're far off. You can combine them with `combineLatest` or `forkJoin` --e.g:

```js
getThings = (): Observable<Thing[]> => 
    this.getThingIds().pipe(
        mergeMap((thingIds: number[]) => {
            const things$ = [];
            thingIds.forEach((id: number) => things$.push(this.http.get<Thing>(`url${id}`)));
            return forkJoin(things$);
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to give a solution that's a bit more performant. While `forkJoin()` does accomplish this, you subscriber must wait until all `Thing`s have been fetched before emitting data.

The following solution accomplishes the same thing, but gives you an array that grows as each HTTP request is completed.

```
getThings$ = this.getThingIds$.pipe(
  switchMap((ids:number[])=>
    from(ids).pipe(
      mergeMap(id=>this.http.get<Thing>(`url${id}`)),
      scan((things, thing)=>[...things, thing], [] as Thing[])
    )
  )
);
```

Here's the line-by-line

- We start with `switchMap()` instead of `mergeMap()`. Merge maps create a queue while switch maps will interrupt any in progress http requests. If we get a new array of ids, we don't want to wait for all old ids to resolve first.
- Next we use `from()` which will create an observable that emits each value of our `id` array.
- Now we setup our http queue using `mergeMap()`.
- Next up is the `scan()` operator, which is like `Array.reduce()` but triggers the inner function for every value emitted from the previous line (the HTTP queue). We use a spread operator to add each new `Thing` to our accumulated response.

**Note:** I changed the methods to variables since none of them required any parameters. It just removes the tiniest bit of boilerplate.